# Postgresql internal record id / creation date

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to determine whether or not postgresql  keeps internal (but accessible via a query) sequential record ids and / or record creation dates.

In the past I have created a serial id field and a record creation date field, but I have been asked to see if Postgres already does that.  I have not found any indication that it does, but I might be overlooking something.

I'm currently using Postgresql 9.5, but I would be interested in knowing if that data is kept in any version.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

No is the short answer.

There is no automatic timestamp for rows in PostgreSQL.

You could create the table with a timestamp with a default.

```
create table foo (
foo_id serial not null unique
, created_timestamp timestamp not null
    default current_timestamp
) without oids;
```

So

```
insert into foo values (1);
```

Gives us

[image: Results of default current_timestamp column]

You could also have a modified_timestamp column, which you could 
update with an after update trigger.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, this helps. In the past I have by default included a timestamp field for record creation date and one for update date, as well as a serial id field used for paging.  We have been discussing whether or not Postgresql might already have those fields, and it seems that it does not.

Comment: Thats fine @user2333312 To be honest I used the above in a live high transaction site. It works fine and is a kind of  "generic" solution for most Db's. All the best

Comment: Couldn't a user use the xmin and xmax columns?

Comment: A good point @DanielL.VanDenBosch "In the past, I have created a **serial id** field **and** a record creation **date field**, **but** I have been asked to see if Postgres **already does that.**"